# What can be used to open .ccitt files?

Tags: graphics, file-format

`pdfimages` extracted from pdf file `.-000.ccitt` and `.-000.params`

How can I open it? Searching finds spam farms with automatically generated text about extensions.

Comment: I changed `pdfimages` paremeters and it managed to produce something else, still I am curious how this file can be opened.

Comment: Do not know how you searched Google gave me lots of good results when I searched for what are ccitt files.

Comment: @David I know what ccitt file is - that is not a problem. I do not know how to open it on Ubuntu.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and found [fax2tiff](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/fax2tiff.htm), but it fails with `Not enough memory.`. Then I found [this blog](https://schnee.livejournal.com/1917916.html) that mentioned [this implementation](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2011/08/ccitt-encoding-in-pdf-files-converting-pdf-ccitt-data-into-a-tiff/) in Java, which someone with a little bit more time and expertise than me might get to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to tiff with fax2tiff, .ccitt is the raw file  and .params are the options needed by tif2fax.
This script does everything

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.ccitt
do
    b=${f%.ccitt}
    p=$(cat $b.params)
# enable if necessary    rm -f $b.tiff
    fax2tiff $p -o $b.tiff $b.ccitt
done
```